# cakephp form validation password comparision

Tags: forms, validation, cakephp, passwords

I have a function to reset a password.
At the point where I have to compare the password and the password_confirm field, I get a strange behavior:

My form

```
echo $this->Form->hidden('tkn', array('value' => $tkn));
echo $this->Form->hidden('uid', array('value' => $uid));
echo $this->Form->input('password',array('type' => 'password', 'name' => 'data[Appuser][password]'));
echo $this->Form->input('password_confirm',array('type' => 'password', 'name' => 'data[Appuser][password_confirm]'));
```

My model validation:

```
var $validate = array(
        'password' => array(
            'rule'    => array('minLength', '6'),
            'message' => '{password} minLength 6!'
        ),
        'password_confirm' => array(
            'rule'    => array('equaltofield','password'),
            'message' => '{password_confirm} not equal!'
        ),
    );

function equaltofield($val1, $val2){
        return $this->data[$this->alias][key($val1)] == $this->data[$this->alias][$val2];
    }
```

My Controller:

```
if($this->Appuser->save($this->data)){

                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Password has been updated'));

            }else{
                debug($this->Appuser->invalidFields());
            }
```

Now:
When I submit an empty form I get the following returned from the invalidFields()

```
array(
    'password' => '*****',
    'password_confirm' => array(
        (int) 0 => '{password_confirm} not equal!',
        (int) 1 => '{password_confirm} not equal!'
    )
)
```

Question 1: Why do I not get the message, that the password has not its minlength?
Question 2: Why do I get the second message twice for comparing the password?

When typing in 2 different password with min length, I get this again:

```
array(
    'password_confirm' => array(
        (int) 0 => '{password_confirm} not equal!',
        (int) 1 => '{password_confirm} not equal!'
    )
)
```

When debug($this->data) I also get this (if that helps somehow)

```
array(
    'Api' => array(
        'tkn' => '6837d241bf1076c3c55a95abbcfafa04dc19a33c',
        'uid' => '1'
    ),
    'Appuser' => array(
        'password' => '*****',
        'password_confirm' => 'asdfgh'
    )
)
```

Any ideas regarding my two questions above?
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var $validate = array(
        'password' => array(
            'rule'    => array('minLength', '6'),
            'message' => '{password} minLength 6!'
        ),
        'password_confirm' => array(
            'rule'    => 'equaltofield',
            'message' => '{password_confirm} not equal!'
        ),
    );

function equaltofield($data){
        return $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] == $this->data[$this->alias]['password_confirm'];
    }
```